# How to set Page Scaling to none while exporting crystal report to PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, crystal-reports

Iam using Crystal reports(version:11) , I am exporting these reports to PDF, i want to set page scaling of the exported PDF to 'None', Is der any way to do that ??

Answer (score 0):

When Crystal exports to PDF, there is no page scaling.  If you find that the report is getting shrunk or stretched to fit a printed page, that is more related to the PDF print driver you are using.